# swift how to resize navigation bar from code

Tags: swift, navigationbar

I can't add nav bar from storyboard but I need it. 
I tried so:

```
let navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 44))
    self.view.addSubview(navBar);
    let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "SomeTitle");
    let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: nil, action: "selector");
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneItem;
    navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false);
```

But I get something like this:
[image]

ok how to set the nav bar centered and to fix the size like normal nav bar on the view?
I've tried even that:

```
let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: navBar, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([xConstraint])
    self.view.addConstraint(xConstraint)
```

it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure that the `view` that you call is the full width of the screen?

Comment: try embedding your ViewController in UINavigationController in Storyboard

Comment: you can create a navigationController programatically and push or present your controller from that navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new NavigationController and present you desired controller. I am assuming that you are on `viewController1` and want to present `viewController2`. So you can do something like below

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController2())
        navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = true
        // customize according to your need

        self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: {

        })
```